# Is there a i18n function called when language changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, formik

Problem -> I'm trying to make a validation that changes the Formik error message when the language is switched, but Formik does not automatically change the error only if I hit the submit button calling `"formik.onSubmit"` or updating the fields in the form so the error messages get updated when I type `"formik.handleChange"`.

Attempts -> So I tried to use `useEffect` hook to update the Formik errors :

```
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(formik.errors);

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrors(formik.errors);
  }, [formik.errors]); 

  <Error>{errors.email}</Error>
```

But it didn't work, only changes when I click the submit button or update the field. So my second attempt was forcing a click on the submit button when language changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (formik.errors.email !== undefined)
      document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
  }, [i18n.language]);
```

It worked but when i first render the page it calls the `useEffect` rendering the errors even the form was not touched, so the `useEffect` is working as `ComponentDidMount` and `ComponentDidUpdate` (the only i want).
So, is there a function or props for i18n that i can put on useEffect to only call when language changes?

Comment: i do not believe there is anything built in - but you could write a timer that polls against the properties and raise your own event

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue and I am not sure if this link will help: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1591

Comment: https://medium.com/code-divoire/how-to-internationalize-a-yup-validation-schema-in-a-react-formik-and-react-i18next-app-689ff3cd978
https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1395    Those 2 links helped me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked if the `formik.errors` object was empty so it blocked the click event, if not, changes the language of error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.entries(formik.errors).length !== 0)
      document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
  }, [i18n.language]);
```